Best practices for saving parent and children records
I took over a project and there is a function to create a record in the database. However, there are many child records in various tables for a parent record. The process for the code:

Validate the data for the parent object. If it passes ...
Create the child records in various tables.
Create the parent record.
Go back and update all the child records.

There are no foreign keys, and the fields that link to the parent are nullable.
The validation is not thorough, so it may pass when it should fail. Child records are created, but then the parent record has DB errors because the data lengths are exceeded. We fix the validation, but then other aspects of the site fail, and we are having to roll back changes.

"so the validation may pass when it should fail." - then why not fix that?

BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK or COMMIT.

Step 2 is missing an action/verb. Do you mean "Create the children records in various tables"? Or did you mean to put the "Create" word in step 2 and accidentally put it on step 1?

"We fix the validation, but then other aspects of the site fail, and we are having to rollback changes." What do you mean by "other aspects of the site fail"? What site are you talking about? I thought this was a MySQL database question? Also, on that point, are you using MySQL or are you using Mariadb?

Start a transaction.
Insert the child rows.
Try to insert the parent row.
If any of this fails, then rollback the transaction.
If all of it succeeds, then commit the transaction.
Obviously, all the tables must be defined using the same type of transaction-capable storage engine. E.g. InnoDB, which is the default storage engine.

Thanks for your input. We are fixing the validation, we just need to take a step back and make a concerted effort because the system is monolithic, about 15 years old and bit of a mess. Other  parts of the system never used validation for the parent, so they break when we introduce simple validation, like email. It is my opinion  validation needs to be fixed, but also to create the parent record first, and if that works, then create the children. Some of us on the team are at odds about that. I wanted input on that as well. Bill, yes, it is PHP and MariaDB.

Whether you create the parent or children first, I recommend using a transaction wrapped around all these inserts. Then you can be sure either they are all committed or else none are committed.
